# How to calculate the average score in struct function of C++?

Tags: c++, struct

This is the question that I was aasigned.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/efRFk.png

And this is my coding. This is my first time asking question here so I dont really know how to paste my coding here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCOBG.png

I really hope someone can help me out. Thank you.

Comment: [Please post text as text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: A couple problems. `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { double sum = sum + student1.test[1]; }` you're declaring a new variable `sum`, whose scope is just the body of that `for` loop. It doesn't have any relationship to the `sum` declared earlier in `main` which is used later to compute `average`. Second, you never initialize `sum` with a value, so when you use it later it's not giving sensible outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below shown program as a starting point(reference). In your program you were creating an ordinary(nonmember) `double` named `average` while according to the assignment `average` should be a data member as shown below. **Second**, there is **no need** to create a separate variable called `sum` because you can use variable `average` to sum all the test scores and then divide average by 3 which is also shown below.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Result
{
    public:
        //this takes input from user
        void takeTestInput()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(test)/sizeof(int); ++i)
            {
                std::cout<<"Input#"<<i+1<<": ";
                std::cin >> test[i];//take the input and put into test[i]
            }
        }
        
        void calculateAverage()
        {
            
            for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(test)/sizeof(int); ++i)
            {
                average+=test[i];    
            }
            average = average/3; 
        }
        
        void printAverage()
        {
            std::cout<<average;
        }
    private:
        int test[3];
        double average; //data member called average 
};

int main()
{
    Result student1;
    
    //take input for student1
    student1.takeTestInput();
    
    //calculate average for student1
    student1.calculateAverage();
    
    //check if the average calculated above is correct by printing out the average for student1
    student1.printAverage();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/v0UHyPmfW).

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the variable `sum`

When you run the code, `sum` is created in the memory.

but it has no value if you don't initialize with value such as 0, 1, 2 ... anything you want.

then, `sum` will take any value which exists in the assigned memory.

that's why the sum of `sum` has a junk value.

Thus, you have to initialize `sum` as below.

`double sum =0.0;`